# Cannot resolve symbol 'QueueMessagingTemplate'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-messaging

I'm currently working on library using spring boot 2.7. In the process of migrating to spring boot 3.1.4 I got an error on a class where:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
```

not found.
Eventhough I have the jar present in the classpath but still cannot find the class.

I already cleared the cache, refreshed the gradle dependencies

the gradle file contain the following dependencies:

```
implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:${property('spring-cloud-aws-dependencies.version')}"))

spring-cloud-aws-dependencies.version = 2.2.6.RELEASE
```

Comment: share the gradle file content as well

Comment: I just did share the dependecencies

Comment: You are using an old AWS cloud dependency. The coordinates moved see https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-aws.

Comment: When I checked the newer dependecy I don't see the class  QueueMessagingTemplate. does that mean that is was removed and should be replaced by anther class ?

Comment: Yes, try to use spring-cloud-aws-messaging Ref: pom file https://github.com/spring-attic/aws-refapp/blob/main/pom.xml. Similarly you do it in  gradle file to define the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the SDK with Spring Boot 3, you should change to new dependencies and migrate to the new messaging approach:

```
 <!-- For SQS -->
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-sqs</artifactId>
 </dependency>

 <!-- For SNS -->
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-sns</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Note that using the `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` dependency won't solve the issue, as it's not designed for Spring Boot 3, and you'll still probably miss some classes during runtime. I assume that you are using `QueueMessagingTemplate` to send to SQS; if that's the case, you can give a try to `SqsTemplate` to [achieve the same](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.3/reference/html/index.html).